# displaying a dialog from a sms receiver in android

Tags: android, dialog

I have a smsReceiver and whenever i get a sms i want trigger a poppup.My method of smsreceiver is getting triggered whenever a sms comes. Then i try to invoke a dialogbox

```
@overide //of smsreciver class
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
  showNotificattion(context)
}

private void showNotificattion(Context context){
        Log.d("sms","showing notification now 2");

         // Create out AlterDialog
          Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
          //even tried context.getApplicationcontext()
          builder.setMessage("This will end the activity");
          builder.setCancelable(true);
          builder.setPositiveButton("I agree", new OkOnClickListener());
          builder.setNegativeButton("No, no", new CancelOnClickListener());
          AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
          dialog.show();
}
```

But whenever a sms comes i get following

```
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:566)
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:179)
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    at com.example.xsms.SmsReceiver.showNotificattion(SmsReceiver.java:92)
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    at com.example.xsms.SmsReceiver.doTask(SmsReceiver.java:73)
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    at com.example.xsms.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:44)
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2103)
07-25 14:02:04.235: E/AndroidRuntime(17935):    ... 10 more
```

How to fix this?
And i want to run my app as a background service and the dialog should be visible

Comment: why is onone answering?is this silly?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong `Context`

A `BroadcastReceiver` or a `Service` cannot start a Dialog.

You should make an `Activity` with a dialog theme and launch it with `startActivity()`

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: Thanks for repltying.Can you please give a example how can i start a activity from onReceive?

Comment: Just create a normal activity (with that theme) and start it with startActivity(new Intent(YourBroadcast.this, YourActivity.class));

Comment: You will also have to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to intent to start Activity from Receiver.